# How to enable Iframe Mode Ckeditor 4

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

In CKeditor 3,
When i call method `CKEDITOR.replace('#textAreaId')` it has an iframe wrapped all ckeditor.
But in CKEditor 4, i call same medthod (not inline) but iframe lost. How can i force CKEDITOR render in an iframe? Thanks.

**Update 1**

I use `CKEDITOR.replace('textAreaId')`. Editor show but no iframe wrapped.

Answer (score -1):

CKEditor **never** accepted CSS queries in `CKEDITOR.replace`. So that code would never work.

If you downloaded one of default CKEditor packages, then you need to call:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'textareaid' );
```

See [`CKEDITOR.replace` docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-replace).

Comment: Unfortunately you didn't gave us enough information. I don't know from where did you get CKEditor, how is it configured, if there are any errors and how exactly do you check existence of an iframe etc.